# removing empty parameters from query string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long query string which also contains empty parametes. I am trying to delete that empty ones by using RegEx

e.g

```
var abc = "w=01.05.2014&x=15&y=&z="
```

in this case for example the parameters y and z are empty. So I would like to remove these 2.

```
abc.replace(/[a-zA-z]+=(?=&|$)/, "")
```

But I think positive lookahead will not work in Javascript.

Comment: Empty parameters are potentially meaningful...

Comment: Anyway, `abc.replace(/(?:^|&)[a-zA-z]+=(?=&|$)/g, "")` - need global flag and to remove the `&` from the start (otherwise you get `&x=15&&`)

Comment: abc = abc.match(/[^\&\=]+\=[^\&]+/g,'').join('&')

Comment: `abc.replace(/(&?\w+=((?=$)|(?=&)))/g,'');`. Check out [lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead) on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: It will work, you just need to add `//g` flag so it replaces all of the occurrences.